# Calculate average across multiple columns in same row across entire table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, average, calculated-columns

I would like to calculate the daily average weight gain per day for each row and add the answer in a  a new column.

The variable to calculate the average are located all in the same table (Raw Data) and same row but throughout multiple columns.( Body Weight Yest 1, Body Weight Yes 2).

Not all data is available. **How do I calculate average across multiple columns in same row in Power Bi?**

**I have solved the issue by creating following columns with formulas:**

**Total Across Columns**

```
Total Across Columns= [Body Weight Yest 1.] + [Body Weight Yest 2.]
```

**Non Blank Columns**

```
Non Blank Columns=
IF ( ISBLANK ( [Body Weight Yest 1.] ), 0, 1 )
  + IF ( ISBLANK ( [Body Weight Yest 2.] ), 0, 1 )
```

**Body Weight Daily AVG.**

```
Body Weight Daily AVG = [Total Across Columns] / [Non Blank Columns]
```

[image: Data Table for Body Weight Calculation]

in Power Query  (Excel Add On):

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(Raw Data[@[ Body Weight Yest. 1]:[ Body Weight Yest. 2]];"<>");"")
```

**I would like to know if there is a simpler/better solution?**

Comment: Solved the Issue. However would like to know if there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you can restructure your model, the approach I would take is to unpivot your data with `Table.Unpivot` in M:

```
let
  <your existing query>,
  Unpivoted = 
    Table.Unpivot(
      <your prior last step>,
      {"Body Weight Yest 1", "Body Weight Yes 2"},
      "Measurement",
      "Value")
  RemoveNulls = Table.SelectRows(Unpivoted, each [Value] <> null)
in
  RemoveNulls
```

This would take your multiple columns and make them rows. The column headers are now values in the new column, [Measurement], and the values which were in the individual columns are now all in the new column, [Value], and have the appropriate label in the [Measurement] column.

Now, you can define your average as follows:

```
Total body weight = SUM ( 'Raw Data'[Value] )
```

```
Measurement count = DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Raw Data'[Measurement] )
```

```
Average measurement = DIVIDE ( [Total body weight], [Measurement count] )
```

In general, unpivoting is a very powerful transform and very useful to help DAX get more efficient and easier to write. Tall tables are good tables.

Comment: Thank you for the Information. However I get the following error message "Expression error: We cannot convert the value true to type Table. Details: Value= True Type=Type.

Comment: The Code is as follows:

Comment: Unpivoted = 
    Table.Unpivot(#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns (Shortend due the restriction) ",
      {" Body Weight Yest. 1", " Body Weight Yest. 2"},
      "Measurement",
      "Value"),
  RemoveNulls = Table.SelectRows(Unpivoted, each [Value] <> null)
in
  RemoveNulls

  RemoveNulls = Table.SelectRows(Unpivoted, each [Value] <> null)
in
  RemoveNulls

Comment: Would it not be possible to use the Unpivot Function in the Transform Menu? With the same result? Thank You

Comment: @Totti, yes you can absolutely use the GUI to generate the code for you. All GUI actions in Power Query generate code. Additionally, editing the code will be reflected in the Applied Steps. It just happens to be a lot easier to paste the code than to record a gif and write a step-by-step for the GUI actions.  As evidence of this functionality, you can take an existing query and inspect its code in the Advanced Editor, seeing that there is nothing but raw M code - no annotations or anything to do with the GUI actions. Paste that text into a new query - all of the applied steps are still there.